# Android draw Bitmaps fast

Tags: android, android-layout

```
Bitmap top;
int x;
public ViewExample() {
    top = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.top);

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                x++;
                postInvalidate();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.drawBitmap(top, x, 0, null);
}
```

I try to draw movable bitmap fast , what to do to make draw fast? (it is very slow and not smooth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using View class to create surface it will be very slow , so use SurfaceView .

Surface view is used for create frequently changing surface .

Go [Her](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-ii,772.html)e for learn more .

Comment: ah thank you I try with surfaceview and is smooth and fine, but can I make surfaceview transparent background?

Comment: set paint Color transparent 0X00000000 can make the view transparent .

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using too much power of your phone. You need to let the thread sleep every now and then. 40 ms is a nice time giving you 25 fps.

Heres an example

```
public ViewExample() {
    top = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.top);

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                x++;
                postInvalidate();

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```